# Upgraded from IIS6 to IIS8 now SQL statement no longer working

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Thanks for the help

I have recently upgraded from IIS6 to IIS8 and all of my web applications are working correctly except 1.

I have an adodb.connection and it is no longer pulling the correct data from my database. Nothing on the database side has changed.

it looks like it is rounding down on my numbers but I am not sure why it is doing that.

here is my query

```
Set OBJdbConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
OBJdbConnection.Open "DSN=DSNNAME;UID=UIDNAME;PWD=password"
OBjdbConnection.CommandTimeout=0
SQLQuery = "SELECT ACDESC, substr(POINTS,1,5) as Field, AHDATE, AHEMPN, AHCODE, EENAME, YAED10 
FROM (((CKATRCODL1 INNER JOIN CKATRHIS ON ACCODE=AHCODE) 
 INNER JOIN CKEMPLMS ON AHEMPN=EEEMPN) INNER JOIN EMPNOS ON 
EEEMPN=OEMP#) INNER JOIN F060116 ON NEMP#=YAAN8 WHERE AHEMPN=" & 
EmpNum & " ORDER BY AHEMPN, AHDATE"
Set R1 = OBJdbConnection.Execute(SQLQuery)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your last edit comment says *I was able to get it to work by doing a substr on one of the fields* .If your problem is solved, please add that as an answer, and revert the question to its original version.

Answer (score 0):

I was pulling from a packed field record and by adding the substr I was able to get the data I needed.